# odbc driver for ctree java

Tags: netbeans, connection, odbc, driver

I'm doing a java application with netbeans and I need to provide a connection using odbc but i don't found the driver beacause the database to connect is a faircom db. Anyone have a link for download a library java (jar) for db connection faircom?

Answer (score 0):

FairCom has a JDBC driver that can access FairCom (c-tree) data through the c-treeACE SQL Server.

Here's the link to the page on FairCom's site where you can download the Express version of c-treeACE, which includes both c-treeACE SQL Server and the JDBC driver:

http://www.faircom.com/ace/download_t.php

Comment: jdbc driver of faircom doesn't work with <9 versions. So i've used a jdbc-odbc bridge using the odbc drivers. Thanks